# Git: "wildcard refspec" with no match on remote, when pulling

Tags: git

I have setup a new Git repository at cloufforge and have some unusual problems.

```
When I do a git pull origin master

From https://dndigital.git.cloudforge.com/project
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

But if a colleague does the same, he keep sgetting the same message over and over again, without getting the "Already up-to-date"

```
remote: Counting objects: 85, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (58/58), done.
remote: Total 76 (delta 59), reused 19 (delta 13)
Unpacking objects: 100% (76/76), done.
From https://dndigital.git.cloudforge.com/project
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
There are no candidates for merging among the refs that you just fetched.
Generally this means that you provided a wildcard refspec which had no
matches on the remote end.
```

Why is this happening please?

**Update:**

I tried the suggested answer and can't see any issue. But it seems the issue is the we use different git clients. Having different versions of Git clients could become problematic it seems. Thats really complicated. Is there a way to limit the features of Git to a certain git version only, so that the earliest Git client can still work?

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = https://username@dndigital.git.cloudforge.com/project.git
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[user]
    name = 
    email = 
[giggle]
    file-view-path = agile/includes/SiteConfig.php
[gui]
    wmstate = zoomed
    geometry = 787x379+512+242 248 420
```

Comment: Happened to me when I tried to pull from mounted (read sshfs) directory.

Answer (score 13):

Hey I just had the same issue, but it was caused by the destination folder being out of space. Might help to check for that if nothing else works.

Comment: Out of disk space caused this error for me as well.

Answer (score 10):

Have a look at your colleague's `.git/config`, it seems git does not know that the remote branch `origin/master` needs to merged into his local `master` branch.

You should have something like this configured

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = ...
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Note that `git pull` does a `git fetch`, then a `git merge` under the hood. You can try it out in steps to see what goes wrong.

```
git checkout master
git fetch origin
git merge origin/master
```